# Solving equations with summation

Tags: calculus

I have this equation

$\lambda_i=\frac{w_i h_i}{g_i \sum_{j=1}h_j p_j(1+\frac{h_ip_i}{\sum_{j=1}{h_jp_j +\sigma^2}})}$.

I want to solve this equation in terms of $p_i$ but I am not sure how to do it because of the summation signs. Can anyone give me a clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,
factor out all the terms
that do not depend on $j$.

Note:
I am not sure if the
$\sigma^2$ is in the sum or not;
I will assume not.

$\lambda_i
=\dfrac{w_i h_i}{g_i \sum_{j=1}h_j p_j(1+\frac{h_ip_i}{\sum_{j=1}h_jp_j +\sigma^2})}
=\dfrac{w_i h_i}{g_i(1+\frac{h_ip_i}{\sigma^2+\sum_{j=1}h_jp_j})} \dfrac1{\sum_{j=1}h_j p_j}
$.

If we now let
$S 
= \sum_{j=1}h_j p_j
$,
this becomes
$\lambda_i
=\dfrac{w_i h_i}{g_i(1+\frac{h_ip_i}{\sigma^2+S})} \dfrac1{S}
=\dfrac{w_i h_i(\sigma^2+S)}{Sg_i(\sigma^2+S+h_ip_i)} 
$.

From this,
$\sigma^2+S+h_ip_i
=\dfrac{w_i h_i(\sigma^2+S)}{g_i\lambda_iS}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
h_ip_i
&=\dfrac{w_i h_i(\sigma^2+S)}{g_i\lambda_iS}-(\sigma^2+S)\\
&=\dfrac{w_i h_i\sigma^2}{g_i\lambda_iS}+\dfrac{w_i h_i}{g_i\lambda_i}-(\sigma^2+S)\\
&=\dfrac{w_i h_i}{g_i\lambda_i}(\dfrac{\sigma^2}{S}+1)-(\sigma^2+S)\\
\end{array}
$

There are a
number of things
you can do
from here.

For example,
if we sum over $i$,
we get

$\begin{array}\\
S
&=\sum_ih_ip_i\\
&=\sum_i\dfrac{w_i h_i}{g_i\lambda_i}(\dfrac{\sigma^2}{S}+1)-\sum_i(\sigma^2+S)\\
&=(\dfrac{\sigma^2}{S}+1)\sum_i\dfrac{w_i h_i}{g_i\lambda_i}-n\sigma^2-S^2\\
&=(\dfrac{\sigma^2}{S}+1)T-n\sigma^2-S^2\\
\end{array}
$

where
$T
= \sum_i\dfrac{w_i h_i}{g_i\lambda_i}
$.

This gives a
cubic equation for $S$.

Once $S$ is gotten,
the $p_i$
can be gotten from
$h_ip_i
=\dfrac{w_i h_i}{g_i\lambda_i}(\dfrac{\sigma^2}{S}+1)-(\sigma^2+S)
$.

Anyway,
hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your time and effort